# Foundation Gem Not working (Windows 8)

Tags: ruby, sass, zurb-foundation

Im new to developing using SASS, but I really want to use Foundation. I have Node JS, Ruby, Compass, SASS, Bower etc.. installed.

1) I open my command and run **C:\Builds> `compass create project`**
   Result: `Congrats! Your compass project has been created`

2) I then run **C:\Builds\Project> `gem install zurb-foundation-5`**
   Result: `Successfully installed zurb-foundation-5-5.2.2`

3) I run **C:\Builds\Project> `foundation new sitename`**
   Result: `foundation is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I Thought I would now have  **C:\Builds\Project\Sitename**

Now that I think of it, realistically I wanted foundation installed inside the original project folder and sass is already running in that directory.

Right now my file structure looks like:

```
project/
├── .sass-cache
│   └── ...
├── sass
│   └── ...
├── stylesheets
│   └── ...
├── config.rb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with Windows 8 and i got the same error.  Foundation doesn't register itself properly for some reason but you can call it explicitly with `ruby <pathToGems>\foundation-1.0.4\bin\foundation new <name>` in my case foundation is in `Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\foundation-1.0.4\bin\`

Comment: Yeah I was using this link to get where I am now. WOndering if you could expand on your answer. I have noted that I am using NodeJS. Bower/Grunt is also installed. If I want foundation to be installed in the project directory. What is my course of action?

Comment: Also on that link, it says `gem install foundation` shouldn't it be `gem install zurb-foundation-5` found at http://rubygems.org/gems/zurb-foundation-5

Comment: @EricB   no it's `gem install foundation`